# How to translate exercise into a time based value?

Tags: python, time, integer

I have started taking a beginner class in python but cannot wrap my head around translating this exercise into time based value:

Exercise:
*"You set off at 8:12am and jog for 1km at 12:10 per kilometre, then  5km at the pace 10:15 per  kilometre and then 1km at 12:10 per kilometre, what time do you finish?"*

What I have so far -

```
import datetime
starttime = datetime.time(8,12,0)
print(starttime)

firstkm = 1
firstpace = 12.10
firststint = firstkm * firstpace
print(firststint)

secondkm = 5
secondpace = 10.15
secondstint = secondkm * secondpace
print(secondstint)

thirdkm = 1
thirdpace = 12.10
thirdstint = thirdkm * thirdpace
print(thirdstint)

runtime = firststint + secondstint + thirdstint
print(runtime)
```

I attempted to multiply time based values and also tried converting at the end of the process. I watched various videos that helped with the time based items but nothing seemed to discuss multiplying values, what am I missing?

Comment: `at 12:10 per kilometre` what does this mean? 12 minutes and 10 seconds for the first kilometer? If so, then your code `firstpace = 12.10` doesn't make sense - 12.1 is a (float) number, rather than a time period. I suspect the exercise is wanting you to look at the `timedelta` class, which represents a duration. Take a look at the `timedelta` in the datetime module.

Comment: I think it is referencing 12 minutes and 10 Seconds - I will check that out! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hours/minutes/... to a `datetime` object by adding a `timedelta`.

```
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timedelta

starttime = datetime.combine(date.today(), time(8, 12, 0))
print(starttime.time())
h = 0.50 // a half hour. // TODO calculate a correct elapsed time
endtime = starttime + timedelta(hours=h)
print(endtime.time())
```

By the way, the elapsed hour seems be `firstkm / firstpace + secondkm / secondpace + thirdkm / thirdpace`